# Accessing the td in a table row by id or class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Each row has a unique ID so I can get the table row. I would then like to update the value for the columns aka TDs based on the the class or ID using JQuery.

```
 <tr onclick="getTableData(this)" id="id_"{{@xref.id}}>
                     <td id="id" class="hidden">{{@xref.id}}</td>
                     <td id="create_ts">{{@xref.create_ts}}</td>
                     <td id="status">{{@xref.status}}</td>
                     <td id="supply_id">{{@xref.supply_id}}</td>
                     <td id="description">{{@xref.description}}</td>
                     <td id="unit">{{@xref.unit}}</td>
                     <td id="hcpcs">{{@xref.hcpcs}}</td>
                     <td id="unitcost">{{@xref.unitcost}}</td>
                     <td id="cap">{{@xref.cap}}</td>
                     <td id="rev">{{@xref.rev}}</td>
                     <td id="buq">{{@xref.buq}}</td>
                     <!-- <td>{{@xref.create_ts}}</td> -->
                   </tr>
```

Something like

```
row.id[buq]=1
```

After much reading I realize I should make these classes and not ids since they are not unique. So a solution involving class would be nice.

Thanks for all the helpful answers! I had a hell of a time finding that misplaced " after id_ on line one of my table row definition! Anyway now that I have switched to classes how can I continue to hide the id table data? I have tried using

```
<td style="visibility:collapse;">
```

But it does not collapse as reported. I am using the bootstrap framework so before as you can see I was using class=hidden to hide my id column

Answer (score 1):

If for example, this is the `html` that you render

```
 <table>
 <tr id="id_1">
   <td class="id hidden">id_1</td>
   <td class="create_ts">create_ts1</td>
   <td class="buq">buq1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="id_2">
   <td class="id hidden">id_2</td>
   <td class="create_ts">create_ts2</td>
   <td class="buq">buq2</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

then, you can access to your specific `td`, by find the specific `tr` you want. this can be done by accessing its ID with `#` tag

```
$('#id_1')
```

after that, what you want to do is search `td` element inside that `tr`, by searching its CLASS with `.` tag

```
$('#id_1').find('.buq')
```

bellow is example jquery to find `td` with CLASS = "buq" bellow `tr` with ID = "id_1", then change it's value :

```
$('#id_1').find('.buq').html('xxx');
```

working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/z5uepdxr/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is your DOM

```
<tr id="row_1">
    <td id="status">Data</td>
    <td id="buq">Data</td>
</tr>
```

Then you can select it like this -

```
$("#row_1 #buq")
```

or

```
$("#row_1 > #buq")
```

If you use classes instead, like

```
<tr class="row_1">
    <td class="status">Data</td>
    <td class="buq">Data</td>
</tr>
```

Then it will look like this

```
$(".row_1 .buq")
```

And to change the value,

```
$(".row_1 .buq").html('Data to be shown inside td');
```

Needless to say, you can set any html inside it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you can simply try below if you want to update them differently -

```
$('#buq')
```

This will give you access to the TD with id 'buq'. Is this you are looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in JQuery to find a child Id inside the container element is by using the Id of the container element.

```
$('#containerId').find('#childId')
```

You can find the element by using the css class as well.

```
$('.containerId').find('.childId')
```

Id is represented by '#' and css class is represented by '.'

Thanks